# Word is refusing to save documents I created--"File Block Settings"

Tags: microsoft-word

I've worked on these documents over the past few years with no problems, on Windows 10. Since a recent software update, Word now gives me an error "You are attempting to save a file type (Word 2007 and later documents and templates) that has been blocked by the File Block settings in the Trust Center."

The error message gives instructions for enabling this file type. In the Trust Center, File Block settings, I've checked all of the items listed. But I'm still getting the error. This is a mess! All I've figured out is to save each document as a PDF, to keep from losing my recent revisions.

Any ideas? Thanks to you folks who pay attention to these issues!

Steve

Comment: You should have the checkbox **unchecked** instead to be able to open and save the file type. So go back to your File Block setting, find the option, and have it unchecked, both on Open and Save checkboxes.

Comment: Would it be an option to save each file in a newer format anyway? If you have many you may find a script that could do this for you easily.

Comment: Vylix, yes, you are right!  Embarrassing that I was going about this exactly backwards--by checking MORE things rather than unchecking them--but very satisfying to have this working again. Thank you!

Comment: The way these options are set up now are completely counter-intuitive

Answer (score 7):

File > Options (at screen bottom) > Word Options Trust Center (at bottom of left pane) > Trust Center Settings button at right > File Block Settings.

Yeah, check marking CAUSES a block.

I clicked the Restore Defaults button in lower right and it cleared all the boxes, and I could now save my file.